# Como deixar o menu dropdown por cima de outros elementos?

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
background-image: img/fundosite.jpg;
}

.gif {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
  
}



body { 
   background: url(img/fundosite.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

  
}

/*.efeito-vidro {
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.35 );
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
    backdrop-filter: blur( 13.5px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 13.5px );
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 );
  }

código html:

<div class="efeito-vidro">
   
<p><br>conteudo</p>


</div>


*/

nav{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}









.menu ul li {
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  
  
  
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #1916d4;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0%;
}

.menu ul ul{
  display: none;
  
  
  }

.menu ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
 
.menu a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;

  
}  



#site{
  /* Definimos a largura da página */
  width:1000px;
  /* Definirmos a altura da página*/
  height:700px;
  /* Aqui definiremos a posição que a página ocupará na tela, nesse caso estamos definindo que fique centralizado na tela*/
  /*top : posição de cima */
  margin-top:0;
  /* left: posição de esquerda*/
  margin-left:auto;
  /* bottom : posição de baixo */
  margin-bottom:0;
  /* right : posição de direita */
  margin-right:auto;
  /* Aqui definiremos a cor de fundo da página */
  background-color:
}




/*abaixo as linhas de codigo para edicao do footer*/
#footer{
  /* definindo a largura da div */
  width:100%;
  /* altura da div */
  height:40px;
  /* Cor de fundo da div */
  background-color:#000000;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  }


/*abaixo as linhas de codigo para posicionamento do buscador*/
.container {
  width: 50%; /* define a largura do campo */ 
  position: relative;  /* cria o contexto de posicionamento do botão */ 
}
label {
  display:block;
}

/* define a largura do campo igual a largura do container */
input {
  width: 100%;
} 



input,  button {
  padding: 10px;
  
}


/* posiciona o botão em relação ao container, mas
  como o campo está exatamente contido no container
  o posicionamento se dá também em relação ao campo */
button {
  position: absolute;   
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Minha Mídia</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="homepage.css" />

  
      <figure class="gif">
      <img src="banner/banner.gif" alt="some text" width=100% height=100%>
      </figure>
  
</head>


  
<body>


<center>
  <div id="header">
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mídias</a>
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Músicas</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Livros</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">Letras</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links</a>
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    </div>
  </center>


    <br><br><br>
   
  <center>
  <div class="container">  
  <form action=" " method="post"></form>
  <label for="busca"></label>
    <input type="search" id="busca" placeholder="Busque músicas, letras ou o que quiser..." name="q">
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </div>
  </center>

  


<div id="footer">
  <center>rodapé</center>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu estou com uma dúvida que é: Como fazer com que o menu dropdown fique por cima de outros elementos da página. Por enquanto, quando posiciono o mouse em cima para que o menu "desça", ele fica por baixo de um buscador que eu coloquei na página.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar a propriedade "z-index: 1" na sua ul

```
//inline
<ul style="z-index: 1;">
...
</ul>

//linkado
<ul class="nav">
...
</ul>

//css
.nav { z-index: 1;}
```

A propriedade **z-index** define a prioridade sobre os elementos, imagine uma pilha de livros contendo **10 livros**, o que estiver embaixo terá uma prioridade **0 (zero)**, e o que estiver em cima terá a prioridade **10 (dez)**, quanto maior a prioridade mais em cima ele ficará.

***Obs: Você pode colocar valores negativos também para a z-index, ex.:  z-index: -1;***

Comment: Meu amigo muito obrigado. Fiz como você me disse e deu muito certo!!!